# PhoneGap window.height less than screen height

Tags: cordova

I'm recently coding with phonegap. And I want to get the scrren height of my device. The screen height of my device should be 854. But when I use the window.innderHeight in JavaScript, I got the value 816. I also tried $.mobile.getScreenHeight() but the value is the same. Can anyone tell me why the value is 816 not the 854? thx